# How to create green coffee?

Tags: brewing-process, beans, green-coffee

On the weekend, I've visited the vienna coffee festival. I've tasted "green coffee" there. Its taste and look was similar to green tea.

Is it a tea, created from the leaves of the coffee?

I tried to search it on google, but I've found "green coffee capsule" advertisements only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have seen online suggests that it is what one would think of as severely under roasted (by coffee standards) coffee.  The flavor profile is very different than traditionally roasted coffee and much closer to tea with a lot of bitterness from compounds that are generally roasted off.

[Sweet Maria's Green Coffee Cupping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OGFui3_5YU&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 2):

Green coffee usually refers to unroasted coffee beans. 
You can make an infusion from them that matches the taste you are describing, with a lot of bitterness and more "tea-like" taste.

> Green coffee beans are coffee beans that have not yet been roasted. The roasting process of coffee beans reduces amounts of the chemical
>   chlorogenic acid. Therefore, green coffee beans have a higher level of
>   chlorogenic acid compared to regular, roasted coffee beans.
>   Chlorogenic acid in green coffee is thought to have health benefits
>   for heart disease, diabetes, weight loss, and others.
>
> Green coffee became popular for weight loss after it was mentioned on
>   the Dr. Oz show in 2012. The Dr. Oz show referred to it as “The green
>   coffee bean that burns fat fast” and claims that no exercise or diet
>   is needed. How does it work? Green coffee beans are coffee beans that
>   have not yet been roasted. These coffee beans contain a higher amount
>   of the chemical chlorogenic acid. This chemical is thought to have
>   health benefits. For high blood pressure it might affect blood vessels
>   so that blood pressure is reduced.
>
> For weight loss, chlorogenic acid in green coffee is thought to affect
>   how the body handles blood sugar and metabolism.

http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-1264-green%20coffee.aspx?activeingredientid=1264&activeingredientname=green%20coffee

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely coffee mixed in with matcha (green tea) powder rather than it being 'green coffee'.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a 'Green Tea Latte' at a place I went recently. it looked like this:

[image]

It is not coffee at all, but green tea mixed with microfoamed milk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tea made from coffee, and it's called "Cascara." It is not from the actual seed - but instead from the fruit that surrounds the coffee seed before being processed. You can as well steep the leaves from the coffee shrub, although it's a lot less popular than cascara. I really don't think you have coffee that was not roasted - that sounds miserable...

Answer (score 1):

matcha by itself is not anything near tea or coffee. it never boils to begin with, so am not sure if coffee can come out of it. matcha is not green tea either. it's matcha leaves ground into powder and then specially cooked and mixed to make matcha drink.

Comment: What makes you think he was referring to matcha? Did I miss something?

Comment: at the time i put that answer up, - i couldn't comment on the answer where matcha was mentioned, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee beans are green till roasted.  For the best. Choose well dried coffee beans that are set on tarps to dry beside the road. Sun dried. If not when you buy your coffee at the market ask if they have extra dry beans you can buy. Have them grind them there to your likes. All coffee is made from green coffee beans there natural color till roasted. Some green beans may have a small worm in them. Why they roast them is to kill the worm in the bean. Before grinding for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been drinking it at home for a while now. I really love it. It tastes very different from roasted coffee, so don't try to compare it.
I think much like one wouldn't compare yogurt and whipped cream.
And later in the stomach it feels much better than roasted coffee.

The amount of caffeine is about the same, for the same amount of original beans (their volume and weight changes during roasting, so don't compare by weight).

For preparing I think the main difference in the brew is that it needs a longer cook than roasted beans, because the green are harder (or tougher), it takes more time to soak out their juice. So for example you can't do a quick extraction like in espresso machine.
Another thing, you should not use cold brew - you shouldn't drink coffee absolutely raw - it must be heated at least once. So roasted coffee is already cooked, and you can do cold brew, but green coffee must be cooked before it's drunk. I'm not sure how bad raw coffee would be to your health wise, I heard somewhere on the web that it's bad, I dunno, it tastes like shit, and I wouldn't try it myself.

Preferably grind beans first (buy them ground, they're really hard to grind), because it extracts more efficiently.

Basically just cook the grounds/beans in water, and then drink the water.

- i cook for 60 minutes in a pot on lower than boiling temperature, the closer you get to boil temperature it gives a somewhat different taste, but it's all great I think, just try. You can cook for 10-15 minutes too, but I think you'd extract less from the same amount of beans. Mixing the water will extract faster. Keep it closed so it doesn't get too much air during long cook, the less it oxygenizes the fresher is tastes I think. A well-covered pot with just a small whole for water vapor is good.
- Otherwise when I can't stay home to cook it, I just put the ground coffee in a thermos and fill it up with water about 80-90'celsius and seal it, so the heat is preserved, and it gets "cooked" for a couple of hours and then I drink it. Usually I shake it every few minutes to get it to extract better.
- I think it stays very fresh for a few hours in a sealed thermos (don't let it touch air too much).

On the web some people suggest to soak the beans for 12 hours before cooking.
It’s more complicated to do I think. Depending on the original processing these beans had (wet or dry process), they might get too fermented. I only tried it once, and it was too fermented for my taste.
But if you have the time, I’d recommend trying it, my guess if done well it could be very nice, like sprouted legumes.