# How is green coffee different from usual black coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, green-coffee

I recently saw green coffee on the shelves. I do not know how to prepare it - should I treat it like regular coffee? Or is another technology used?

Answer (score 1):

The green coffee beans are, if not spared for home-roasting, are very lightly roast coffee beans. They are known to be very fruity and light when brewed. You may try to use the regular coffee brewing methods but the result may taste too weak. You may also try to brew them for longer periods just like any other "herbal tea". I assume, longer periods in a French-press would do it. You may try different periods to find your desired taste.

Please see this previous discussion on green coffee:

- [How to create green coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/how-to-create-green-coffee/2435#2435)